# How can I write an Excel plugin that loads a SQL Server data table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

My goal is to add a button on my custom excel ribbon that loads a data table the same way as if you click on Data->From Other Sources->From SQL Server.

The object model is so big, I'm having trouble finding the right path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the walkthrough examples from Microsoft:

**For the Add-In itself**

[Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx)

**For the custom Ribbon Tab**

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx)

**For deploying the Add-In**

[VSTO 2010 Deployment in Enterprise environment](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/10a6df09-9e89-47b1-9e89-f8a7880a1636)

Comment: Aaron, did you ever find out how to do this?