# How can I include .NET 4 Tools for Office with my Application?

Tags: .net, ms-office

I have created an installer for my Application, but when I run it on my Testing Machine, its says, "You must install .NET Framework v4 to continue installation." So I go to Microsoft's website and download the .Net framework and install it. However, when I re-install it, it still does not want to install. So I searched on Google for it and it says  I must download .NET Framework Tools for Microsoft Office. I cannot find that, however. Where is it, and how can I include it with my Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Microsoft Whitepaper on [Deploying a Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Solution Using
Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff937654.aspx).

It describes in detail how you need to build your installer.

Other links I found helpfull can be found in my answer on [How can I write an Excel plugin that loads a SQL Server data table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126691/).