# Create installer for add-in in Excel 2007

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, add-in

I have created an add-in for Excel 2007 in visual studio. How do I make an installer / get it onto other peoples computers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the links provided in [my answer dealing with Excel 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932342/how-can-i-include-net-4-tools-for-office-with-my-application/6932533#6932533) - you should be able to adopt most of it for Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

If your add in is an XLA or XLL: Installing means: copy it to
%APPDATA%/Microsoft/Excel/XLStart

Doing so, the add-in will be loaded upon startup (except if the user disabled macros or s.th. like that).

(%APPDATA% is a user specific folder).